# Insert rows if they do not exist in the database pyscopg2 without primary key

Tags: python-3.x, database, postgresql, row, psycopg2

I have a complex PSQL database. I create that using the module psycopg2 from python3. The issue is that in this database it is not possible to have a primary key because it has so many complex data, and each value of each row can be repeated.
This is an example of the data I am working with:

```
S2(155-169),EELQNKILTATVDNA,139,153,NP_000413.1,9606,1772872,Homo sapiens,T cell,Macrophage,HLA-DR7,MHC II,IFNg release,Positive,NA
16,GAGGQAAGGNAANKKAEDAG,269,288,CAC82081.1,10000378,3867109,Homo sapiens,T cell,PBMC,HLA class II,MHC II,IFNg release,Positive,NA
A1-16,GIVEQCCTSICSLYQL,90,105,P01308.1,9606,5993676,Homo sapiens,T cell CD4+,PBMC,HLA class II,MHC II,IFNg release,Positive,NA
```

The thing is that I'd like to insert rows when they do not exist in the psql database, so the table can be updated. And it should be done with psycopg2. I've tried so many things but none seems to work for me. Now I've just been able to create a PSQL file that just insert every row to the PSQL table.

```
   f = open("database.sql", "rt", encoding="utf-8")
   while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line: break
        cursor.execute(line.strip("\n"))
```

I've tried the 'WHERE NOT EXIST' and some more but It always give me some error. If someone does know how to implement psycopg2 to insert only rows that do not exist It would help me a lot.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you cannot determine uniqueness from the fields in each row then `WHERE NOT EXIST` and the like will not work. So you will need to figure out whether there is a set of fields that determine uniqueness and use them as `PRIMARY KEY`.  Or you have to come with a hash of the data to use for comparison. Off hand I would say the data model is not well thought out.

Comment: Your table appears to contain the results of an experiment. Several groups of columns could be normalised into `dimension` tables, leaving only a `fact` table with references to the dimension tables plus the actual measurement (date, number, outcome, ...)